# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery within combined presentation plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a presentation working with the [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/3) conjoined with features of this [flipin plugin](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php) , but I lose the flip effect which is the desired feature and get

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery

with ref to line 1 or simply the error message if I change something -I've tried all the popular and not so popular variances on the variable. This would be common except the code works perfectly fine on in it's own ,so I'm puzzled.

The problem code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */ 
    $('.sponsorFlip').bind("click",function(){      
        // $(this) point to the clicked .sponsorFlip element (caching it in elem for speed):        
        var elem = $(this);     
        // data('flipped') is a flag we set when we flip the element:       
        if(elem.data('flipped'))
        {
            // If the element has already been flipped, use the revertFlip method
            // defined by the plug-in to revert to the default state automatically:             
            elem.revertFlip();          
            // Unsetting the flag:
            elem.data('flipped',false)
        }
        else
        {
            // Using the flip method defined by the plugin:             
            elem.flip({
                direction:'lr',
                speed: 350,
                onBefore: function(){
                    // Insert the contents of the .sponsorData div (hidden from view with display:none)
                    // into the clicked .sponsorFlip div before the flipping animation starts:                      
                    elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
                }
            });         
            // Setting the flag:
            elem.data('flipped',true);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Any ideas?

I'm thinking maybe I missed something in the html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>HUE2</title>

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/zenburn.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div id="reveal">

        <!-- Used to fade in a background when a specific slide state is reached -->
        <div class="state-background"></div>

        <!-- Any section element inside of this container is displayed as a slide -->
        <div class="slides">
            <section>


    <div id="main">
                <div class="sponsorListHolder">


            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip">

                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>






            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip">

                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip">

                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip">

                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
                <div class="sponsorFlip">

                </div>

                <div class="sponsorData">
                    <div class="sponsorDescription">

                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorURL">

            </div>
                </div>
            </div>









    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
        <!-- The navigational controls UI -->
        <aside class="controls">
            <a class="left" href="#">&#x25C4;</a>
            <a class="right" href="#">&#x25BA;</a>
            <a class="up" href="#">&#x25B2;</a>
            <a class="down" href="#">&#x25BC;</a>

        </aside>

        <!-- Displays presentation progress, max value changes via JS to reflect # of slides -->
        <div class="progress"><span></span></div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional libraries for code syntax highlighting and classList support in IE9 -->
    <script src="lib/highlight.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/classList.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/reveal.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>





    <script>


        // Parse the query string into a key/value object
        var query = {};
        location.search.replace( /[A-Z0-9]+?=(\w*)/gi, function(a) {
            query[ a.split( '=' ).shift() ] = a.split( '=' ).pop();
        } );

        // Fires when a slide with data-state=customevent is activated
        Reveal.addEventListener( 'customevent', function() {
            alert( '"customevent" has fired' );
        } );

        // Fires each time a new slide is activated
        Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
            // event.indexh & event.indexv
        } );

        Reveal.initialize({
            // Display controls in the bottom right corner
            controls: true,


            // Display a presentation progress bar
            progress: true,

            // If true; each slide will be pushed to the browser history
            history: true,

            // Loops the presentation, defaults to false
            loop: false,

            // Flags if mouse wheel navigation should be enabled
            mouseWheel: true,

            // Apply a 3D roll to links on hover
            rollingLinks: true,

            // UI style
            theme: query.theme || 'neon', // default/neon

            // Transition style
            transition: query.transition || 'default' // default/cube/page/concave/linear(2d)
        });

        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

```
</body>
```

Does anyone see something I don't?

Comment: are you sure you loaded jquery and the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the [Flip plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) needs jQueryUI.

Also you need to include jQuery first, like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/highlight.js"></script>
<script src="lib/classList.js"></script>    
<script src="js/reveal.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Owlvark -yea all that's loaded too